# Accumulation points in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M$ a metric space, $A \subset M$, $a_0$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if  and only if for every neighborhood $V$ de $a_0$, $V \cap A$ contains a point $a \ne a_0$ such that $a \in A$

I do not how can I begin this prove with metric space, I stuck in this excessive, can someone help me please?...

Comment: start with your definition of accumulation point

Comment: If d(x,A\{x}) =0

Comment: that is for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $y\in A\setminus\{x\}$ with $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ ... it is basically done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_0$ is an accumulation, we have that for every open ball with center on $a_0$ e radiuns $r >0$ $B_r$, $B_r\cap (A - \{a_0\}) \neq \emptyset$, therefore how for every neighborhood $V$ of $a_0$, there is $r>0$ such that $B_r(a_0)\subset  V$, then $V\cap (A - \{a_0\}) \neq \emptyset$.
If for every neighborhood $V$ of $a_0$, we have that $V\cap (A - \{a_0\}) \neq \emptyset$, particularly $B_r(a_0) \cap (A - \{a_0\}) \neq \emptyset$ for every $r>0$.